# How to prove that the equation has real roots

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, roots, real-numbers

How to prove that the following equation has all real roots?
$$\frac{a^2}{(x-m)} + \frac{b^2}{(x-n)} + \frac{c^2}{(x-o)} = p - q^2x $$
where $a,b,c,p,q$ are Real and $m,n,o$ can be Real or Complex.

Comment: Try to put m,n,o as complex numbers of the form Z+iY and proceed

Comment: But if all parameters except $o$ are real, and $c\neq 0$, then the left hand side isn't real for any real $x$, while the right hand side is real for real $x$.

Comment: I did'nt get that "all parameters except o are real" -Daniel Fischer

Comment: @OtherSide0fZer0 Daniel is implying it is a free choice, and his comment is correct.

Comment: @Bacon Ok Got that.

Comment: That's still false after the latest edit. Try for example $a=b=c=1, m=n=o=i, p=0, q=1\,$.